# Scraping data from webpages with scroller using python

Tags: python, scroll, web-scraping

I am interested to scrap all the data from a webpage that when scroll to bottom, you get new data loaded to the page.
Here is an example:
http://stocktwits.com/symbol/CIEN

As you can see if you scroll down the page, more data will load to the page.

How one can scrap all available data for such a page using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is recommended for scrolling http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, it looks interesting I will look into it.

Comment: Man, can your update your link ? This link doesn't work.
i can't see which part of selenium you attached here :/

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page